# Strange message at Debian login. What does it mean?

Tags: debian, command-line

In an attempt to learn more on the command-line I added Debian-7.4-Standard to my Acer-Aspire-One laptop. I am not sure as to what I did exactly, but after I managed to install the non-free firmware and manually installed network-manager to get a wired connection that worked well enough to use `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`, I started to see a strange message on my login prompt after I had booted into my Debian OS. I wrote out a copy of it and it looks like this on my login prompt:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 7 debian tty1

debian login: [   17.63024] ieee80211 phy0: brcm_ops_config: change monitor mode: false (implement)
[   17.630399] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
[   17.631562] ieee80211 phy0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
```

What does this mean? Is this a problem I need to worry about?

If I hit enter the login prompt returns to just the usual `debian login:` prompt and I can login normally.

---

**Update:**
I just noticed that when there is no WiFi signal my login prompt acts in the normal way. I am only seeing these messages when a WiFi signal is available.

Comment: @HaukeLaging to bad you miss the typo in the title

Comment: Those are kernel log messages, easy to recognize because of the `[   17.63024]` prefix with the uptime. As for what those messages in particular mean: no idea, but they seem related to wifi (`ieee80211 phy0` suggest some wifi-antenna drivers).

Comment: It's probably possible to selectively suppress such messages.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console